# jinja2 python print a variable plus one

Tags: jinja2

In jinja2 templating language, how do I perform simple arithmetic on a variable and print it out? If I do `{{ x + 1 }}`, I got error `Could not parse the remainder: '+ 1' from 'x + 1'`.

`x` is passed in from django backend with `render_to_response('template.html', { 'x': 123 })`

Is this not possible in jinja2 or my code screws up somewhere else?

Comment: Are you sure that's a Jinja2 template and not a Django template? They look similar.

Comment: Oops, I wasn't aware of Django template... OK, then is this possible with Django template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out it was Django template that I'm using. And here's how to do simple math:

`{{ first|add:second }}`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#add